# Extract a list with values whose position is indicated by the values in another column from a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

It's probably pretty obvious in the end but I cannot think of a way to do this. Thanks for your help!

I did a prediction task and as a result I have a DataFrame with the percentages and a column with the predicted class, like so:

```
      Class1 Class2 Class3 Prediction
0     0.99   0.01   0.00   Class1
1     0.15   0.14   0.71   Class3
2     0.05   0.80   0.15   Class2
```

Now I want to access the probability with which a class was predicted. So I want to have a list like below so I can work with it further.

```
0 0.99
1 0.71
2 0.80
```

I have problems finding a way to access only one value of df.Predicted at a time and have no idea how to search for it. How do I get this value or alternatively my desired list? I tried this:

```
values = []
for row in df.Predicted:
    values.append(row)
print(values)
```

but it returns the whole column for each iteration. It also doesn't feel very pandas-like. I am using python 3.5 in case it makes a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [15]: df.lookup(df.index, df.Prediction)
Out[15]: array([ 0.99,  0.71,  0.8 ])
```

or

```
In [23]: df.max(axis=1)
Out[23]:
0    0.99
1    0.71
2    0.80
dtype: float64
```

or

```
In [24]: df.filter(regex='^Class').idxmax(axis=1)
Out[24]:
0    Class1
1    Class3
2    Class2
dtype: object
```

Comment: That works. Thank you! I will accept your answer as soon as the time limit runs out

Comment: @Anita219, glad it helps :)